# Set img src at runtime

Tags: jquery

Here is how I do it:

```
var src = '<%=Url.Content(Server.MapPath("~/AppData/images/myImages/1.jpg"))%>';
$('#imgLocation').attr('src', src);
```

I have a solution with MVC project in it. The code above is in index.aspx, which is in:

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Views\index.aspx
```

Here is the image path:

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\App_Data\myImages\locations\1.jpg
```

When I run my project, the image has src whose value is:

```
src="C:UsersJohndocumentsisual studio 2010ProjectsMyAppMyAppAppDataimagesmyimages.jpg"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) renders the physical location of the image instead of the relative location from the web server

You should drop it entirely:

```
var src = '<%=Url.Content("~/AppData/images/myImages/1.jpg")%>';
```

Comment: But I'm supposed to use Server.MapPath. Do you have any idea why is the code not working?

Comment: Why are you supposed to user `Server.MapPath`? Yes. It's not working because of `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: Why are your images in `AppData` instead of `Content`? Are you sure there's a controller serving these images?

Comment: Because I was told to put the images in App_Data. Can you check pls if the path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are being interpreted as escapes.  You need to escape the backslashes for the path to show correctly, but you probably don't want the file system path to reference an image in a web page.

Comment: That's not it. The result is the same.